# How to parse Json result?

Tags: php, json

Please help me get JSON result - `"col1":"64.7020"` to `$result`.

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-08-28T09:50:07Z","lang":"ru-RU","diagnostics":{"publiclyCallable":"true","url":{"execution-start-time":"1","execution-stop-time":"2","execution-time":"1","content":"http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=c4l1&s=USDRUB=X"},"user-time":"2","service-time":"1","build-version":"0.2.48"},"results":{"row":{"col0":"RUB","col1":"64.7020"}}}}



$tick=file_get_contents('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DUSDRUB%3DX%22%3B&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback='); 


$url = $tick;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$result ??
echo col1 ???????
```

Comment: Try `print_r($data)` to see how the original data structure (encoded as JSON during the transfer) looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You have called file_get_contents twice. $tick will have the json returned by yahoo

```
$tick = file_get_contents('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DUSDRUB%3DX%22%3B&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback='); 

$json_a = json_decode($tick, TRUE);
echo  $json_a["query"]["results"]["row"]["col1"];
```